# Sort Table that primary key start with letter and get last record

Tags: mysql, database, select, sql-order-by, where-clause

this my table

```
+---------+-----------+
| Item_No | Item_name |
+---------+-----------+
|  IL1    |  abc_1    |
|  IL2    |  abc_2    |
|  IL3    |  abc_3    |
|  IL4    |  abc_4    |
|  IL5    |  abc_5    |
|  IL6    |  abc_6    |
|  IL7    |  abc_7    |
|  IL8    |  abc_8    |
|  IL9    |  abc_9    |
|  IL10   |  abc_10   |
|  IL11   |  abc_11   | 
+---------+-----------+
```

I want to Sort my Table by primary key I try this SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM `item_master` 
WHERE Item_No LIKE 'IL%' 
ORDER by I_code DESC LIMIT 1
```

but I gives me IL9 as last one

Comment: Hi, as per you mentioned, I_Code is not your field. it should be Item_No.

Comment: What mysql version?

Comment: I'd recommend to use zero-padded autoincrement during `I_code` building.

Comment: Will there be any value like `IL3T`? or `IL3T1`?

Comment: I'd be sorely tempted to use a surrogate id as the primary key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your could, for example, extract number from "Item_No"(I_code?) and convert it to int:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item_master 
WHERE Item_No LIKE 'IL%' 
ORDER by cast(substring(Item_No, 3) as UNSIGNED) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing here is a wrong ordering by `VARCHAR` I assume, which is a string and it gets ordered lexically, here is a way to fix it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item_master 
ORDER by right(concat('0000', Item_No), 4) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Notice the `0000` (4 zeros) and `right()` function second argument `4` is the character length for the ordering field

Another way to solve it to use [LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

```
SELECT * 
FROM item_master 
ORDER by lpad(Item_No, 100, '0') DESC LIMIT 1
```

here is a working [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3efb0c/5) to check